# apt-offline still fails on Ubuntu 14.04 as of 2014-07-24

Tags: ubuntu

One of the answers in [Debian: updating package lists with apt-offline, --simulate not understood for apt-get update](https://superuser.com/q/737905/228536) mentions that the issue was fixed in Ubuntu 14.04.

However, on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, the command `sudo apt-offline set apt-offline.sig` still fails with the same error messages. Does anyone know whether `apt-offline` will be fixed soon in Ubuntu 14.04, so it can, for example, be used to update offline machines to the upcoming 14.04.1 release?

Comment: I've rewritten your question but I'm confused as to the fact that Jeff's answer does link to a valid patch, as well as the existence of a workaround.

Comment: Thanks Doktoro Reichard for your note.  Yes, I saw that there was a workaround, which I haven't tried yet.  I was just hoping that a fix to apt-offline would be released as part of an ordinary update, which would make it more accessible to "newbies".